# Не могу скачать php7.2 в ubuntu-trusty-64

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, php7

подключился к ubuntu-trusty-64 через vagrant. Попытался скачать php7.2:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2
```

В итоге ошибка:

> E: Unable to locate package php7.2
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'

Но php5 устанавливается без проблем

Comment: А если `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.2`?

Comment: Или первой строкой выполнить `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`?

Comment: Наверное, потому что конкретно эта репа не поддерживает trusty?